# Fonts looks different in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, fonts

I am using Google Web Font's PT-sans

```
font-family: 'PT Sans',Arial,serif;
```

but it looks different in Chrome and Firefox

Is there anything that I need to add so that it looks same in all browsers?

Comment: Different browsers may render fonts slightly differently. You can't change that.

Comment: Unless you want to implement your own font renderer, which would make your website slower than a `<insert slow animal name hare>`.

Comment: @muntoo: Or use images/flash/PDF, which will display more consistently

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: Images and Flash are out, Web Fonts is current trend

Comment: @I-M-JM: I agree.  Also, HTML5/SVG > Flash.  But I'd rather use flash/silverlight/PDF/simple images than try to write a font renderer, as muntoo suggested.  I assume it was a joke, but still..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

css reset may fix the problem, I am not sure .

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/

Comment: Thanks I usually always include reset but on recent  HTML5 project I was using a boilerplate and they didn't include a reset this is exactly what was causing the font to look bad in chrome.

Comment: This worked for me as well, but how do I apply my own stylesheet once this is reset is applied to the header of my html? What I mean by this is that I have my own stylesheet (call it mystyles.css), and I want it to govern the layout and style of the site while still maintaining consistency.

Comment: Okay I figured it out.Just place:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css"> inside of your header *before* your other stylesheet link. If you're having trouble viewing the command @Vasmi provided the link above. I'd recommend the link under "The YUI CSS Foundation" section.

Comment: I tried with reset and normalize both one by one but still different is there. In chrome text looks crispier or possibly smaller. Any new solution?

Comment: Here is the new link to the YUI css reset: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/. I use Google Fonts and css reset didn't make a difference.

Comment: Link is broken :(

Comment: @ValDo you can just search for YUI reset.. https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/ also do note that YUI is not longer maintained.

Comment: you don't need `css` reset it's perfect solution `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;`

Comment: right, but do note that this answer is from Jan 15 '11 .

Comment: @VamsiKrishnaB This page is no longer available

Answer (score 25):

For the ChunkFive font from FontSquirrel, specifying "font-weight: normal;" stopped Firefox's rendering from looking like ass when used in a header. Looks like Firefox was trying to apply a fake bold to a font that only has one weight, while Chrome was not.

Comment: I believe this was the problem I had. Tough one to nail down!

Comment: In my testing, this helps, but the fonts still look different.

Answer (score 12):

For me, Chrome web fonts look crappy until I put the SVG font ahead of WOFF and TrueType.  For example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'source_sans_proregular';
    src: url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.svg#source_sans_proregular') format('svg'),
         url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Even then, Chrome's fonts look thinner than in Firefox or IE.  Chrome looks good at this point, but I usually want to set different fonts in IE and Firefox.  I use a mixture of IE conditional comments and jQuery to set different fonts depending on the browser.  For Firefox, I have the following function run when the page loads:

```
function setBrowserClasses() {
    if (true == $.browser.mozilla) {
        $('body').addClass('firefox');
    }
}
```

Then in my CSS, I can say

```
body { font-family: "source_sans_proregular", Helvetica, sans-serif; }
body.firefox { font-family: "source_sans_pro_lightregular", Helvetica, sans-serif; }
```

Likewise, in an IE-only stylesheet included within IE conditional comments, I can say:

```
body { font-family: "source_sans_pro_lightregular", Helvetica, sans-serif; }
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, nuke the Helvetica specific definition... sans-serif is usually defaulted to the most appropriate Helvetica-like font for the platform.  Arial on windows, Helvetica on OSX, Droid-Sans on Android and Open-Sans on most others.

Comment: When applying this code, the fonts still look different. For example, the lowercase "e", in Firefox the tail curls upwards and in Chrome it's mostly flat. For the lowercase "b", in Firefox there's an extra serif on the bottom-left that isn't present in Chrome.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few fixes.  But usually it can be fixed with:

```
html {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Sometimes it can be due to `font-weight`.  If you are using a custom font with `@font-face` make sure your `font-weight` syntax is correct.  In `@font-face` the idea of the `font-weight`/`font-style` properties are to keep your `font-family` name across different `@font-face` declarations while using different `font-weight` or `font-style` so those values work properly in CSS (and load your custom font -- not "fake bold").

I've seen `-webkit-text-stroke: 0.2px;` mentioned to thicken webkit fonts, but I think you probably won't need this if you use the first piece of code I gave.

Answer (score 5):

I've noticed that chrome tends to make fonts a bit more sharper and firefox a bit smoother.
There is nothing you can do about it. good luck

Comment: That's not true. You can use -webkit-font-smoothing, e.g. http://tanookisuitlabs.com/your-fonts-look-bad-in-chrome-heres-the-fix/

Comment: It may not be true almost two years later.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid font discrepancies across browsers, avoid using css styles to alter the look of the font. Using the font-size property is usually safe, but you may want to avoid doing things like font-weight: bold; instead, you should download the bold version of the font and give it another font-family name.

Answer (score 4):

i found this to be working great :

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 0.7px;
```

or

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
```

experiment with the "0,7" value to adjust to your needs.
The lines are added where you define the bodys font.

here is an example:

```
body {
    font-size: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: lighter;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0.7px;
```

Comment: This works if you use JS to identify browsers and give them different -webkit-text-stroke values based on classes (ie body.chrome, body.firefox)

Comment: Unfortunately, for me, fonts still look different in different browsers after adding this.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2014, Chrome still has a known bug where if the webfont being used has a local copy installed, it choses to use the local version, hence, causing OP rendering issues.

To fix this, you can do the following:

First, target Chrome Browser or OSX (For me, the issue was with OSX Chrome only). I have used this simple JS to get quick Browser/OS's detection, you can chose to do this in any other way you're used to:

https://raw.github.com/rafaelp/css_browser_selector/master/css_browser_selector.js

Now that you can target a Browser/OS, create the following 'new' font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Custom PT Sans';    
    src: url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ptsans/v6/jKK4-V0JufJQJHow6k6stALUuEpTyoUstqEm5AMlJo4.woff) format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The font URL is the same your browser uses when embedding the google webfont. If you use any other font, just copy and change the URL accordingly.

Get the URL here http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700&subset=latin,latin-ext

You may also rename your @font-face custom font-family alias.

Create a simple CSS rule to use that font targeting Browser/OS or both:

```
.mac .navigation a {    
    font-family: "Custom PT Sans", "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

Or

```
.mac.webkit p {
    font-family: "Custom PT Sans", "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

Done. Just apply the font-family rule wherever you need to.

Comment: I should add that Chrome may still display font thickening a little different, so you can normalize this via CSS:  "-webkit-text-stroke: 0.2px;"

Answer (score 2):

Different browsers (and FWIW, different OSes) use different font rendering engines, and their results are not meant to be identical. As already pointed out, you can't do anything about it (unless, obviously, you can replace text with images or flash or implement your own renderer using javascript+canvas - the latter being a bit overboard if you ask me).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for a couple of months. Finally, it got worked by disabling below settings in Chrome browser's settings.

Set "Accelerated 2D Canvas" to "Disabled"
(In the browser's address bar, go to chrome://flags#disable-accelerated-2d-canvas, change the setting, relaunch the browser.)

Since the fix for this issue has clearly changed, I would suggest in general turning off any hardware-accelerated text-rendering/2D-rendering features in the future if this fix stops working.

On Google Chrome 55, this issue appears to have cropped up again. As anticipated, the fix was disabling hardware acceleration, it just changed locations.

The new fix (for me) appears to be:

Settings -> Show advanced settings... -> System
UNCHECK "Use hardware acceleration when available"

https://superuser.com/questions/821092/chromes-fonts-look-off

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be more what we don't set in our CSS than what we do set.
In my case, FF is showing text in the default Times New Roman, while Chrome uses Montserrat as expected.
This happens to be because in Chrome I set Montserrat as the default, while FF has no default.
So, I think that some browser differences are rooted in the browser's configuration rather than in my CSS.