# overflow:hidden looks different on Firefox vs Chrome (CSS)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have the following 2in x 1in barcode I am creating (Must be these dimensions). If the name is too long I want it to `overflow:hidden`. This works great in Firefox, but in Chrome it does not (See screenshots). I am guessing it has something to do with my CSS. I also verified both browsers are at default zoom.

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Working demo:

http://blastohosting.com/barcode_overflow/

As you can tell in Chrome, you can see part of the words at the bottom not completely hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the rounding of the font-size.

Use an interger font-size and it will look the same in both browsers.

Ex: `font-size: 13px;`

EDIT: also I recommend using pixels for the dimensions, using inches may have different displays between browsers (I haven't spotted any difference but I prefer to use pixels in a pixel environment).

Comment: This seemed to do the trick. I had to play with it a little bit for it  to work, but this seemed to do it.

Comment: You must have to be clear, that with using `px` as unit for `font-size` you'll might run into other problems, like no text-zooming in older IEs or problems with Responsive Design on Mobile Devices.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome uses the WebKit rendering engine. Firefox uses the Gecko engine. Both interpret and display type slightly differently, as do the DirectX and Vega graphics engines used in IE9+ and Opera. You can't force browsers to render text identically.

For [sub pixel problems in css](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/)

you can reset your css by http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

More information here [Fonts looks different in Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698564/fonts-looks-different-in-firefox-and-chrome)