# Why does my font look the same for 400 and 500 weight in chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I use Roboto from google fonts and for some reason chrome renders it the same for 400 and 500 and it's just bull. On mozilla everything is fine and dandy but really what's up with chrome? Also a a 400 italic is thiner than a 400 normal at a smaller size. What the actual deuce?

Css with included font:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic);
```

I'd also like to mention i use bootstrap 3.5 so i guess the reset is out of the question

Comment: can you share where you have included the font files?

Comment: Most likely not imported the 500 font weight works fine for me:
http://codepen.io/rikato/pen/qbMxGv

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698564/fonts-looks-different-in-firefox-and-chrome?rq=1

Comment: Check the inspector styles and computed properties to make sure something else isn't overriding your font weight values. As a quick test, use `font-weight: 500 !important;`, see if that fixes it. If so, you'll need to sort out the specificity of your CSS.

Comment: http://puu.sh/mWB0E/813f1bee13.png this is what i get when looking at the codepen you gave me on chrome. i guess that means i have to reinstall the font or something? on mozilla eveything is fine, it's quite strange http://puu.sh/mWB5H/8fc32b45d8.png

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the font is being imported correctly, so I have to assume its an issue with the `font-weight` property being overridden somewhere else, especially if you are using bootstrap.

Check the inspector styles and computed properties on your text element to make sure something else isn't overriding your font weight values. You will see a line through your font-weight value if it is being ignored.

As a quick test, use `font-weight: 500 !important;`, see if that fixes it. If so, you'll need to sort out the specificity of your CSS.